# Reorder/change timestamp on migration files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-migrations, ruby-on-rails-5

One of my migration files is referencing another table/model that will will be created further down the migration sequence.

Postgres doesn't like that:

> PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist

So I wonder if there are any potential problems to manually reorder the migration files (by inventing new timestamps/prefixes)?

The affected tables are already down migrated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run `rake db:migrate` command it compares `schema_migrations` table and migration files located in db/migrate folder. All the migrations which were not executed receive `MigrationClass#up` call then.

So starting from the point when your code is already published and/or migrations are run by other users, changing your migrations timestamps/names may lead to unprocessable migration procedure (as `schema_migrations` will treat a migration with changed timestamp as new, unprocessed one, and try to process it "again"). Possible workaround for this would be to comment the contents of `up` method for a while and uncomment it back after migrations are done. For fun you can also manipulate `schema_migrations` table directly from your db console (adding or removing necessary records). Both of these ways smells like a hack though.

Until then... Everything should work flawlessly.

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me for this same situation, even though it's a hack.

Rails runs migrations in order of the timestamp, and Rails tracks which migrations have been run by the timestamp part of the migration file name, but not by the rest of the file name. So if you need to change the order of two migrations because the earlier one references the later one you can simply switch the 14 digit timestamp portion of the filenames by renaming both migration files. If the timestamp is off by even one digit Rails will think it's a new migration so write them down before changing them.